# How can I click on a button using Selenium WebDriver with Java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

The following is the HTML code for button:

```
<span>
<button class="buttonLargeAlt" onclick="javascript:submitCheckout(this.form);"type="submit">Checkout</button>
</span>
```

I tried `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(.,'Checkout')]")).click();`

It is not working...

Any other ideas? There are 2 buttons with same name on the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
//span/button[text()='Checkout' and @class='buttonLargeAlt']
```

or

```
//span/button[text()='Checkout'][1]
```

Also, if you know which of the 2 buttons you need to click, you can try:

```
//span/button[text()='Checkout'][1]
```

Where `[1]` is the first button found with a text of `'Checkout'`

Answer (score 4):

```
driver.submit()
```

should work. 
If the order of the buttons in your DOM is always the same, this should work too:

```
driver.findElements(By.className("buttonLargeAlt")).get(0).click();
```

if it is the first buttonLargeAlt button on your page.

Answer (score 2):

The followings should work:

```
driver.findElement(By.className("buttonLargeAlt")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(@class='buttonLargeAlt')]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='buttonLargeAlt']")).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    You can achieve this by using XPath with html input element id or by name
    //1. By XPath indexing option:  
    WebElement loginButtonId = 
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='login']"));
    //Xpath of login button i have get For firefox browser

    loginButtonId.click();

    I hope this work for you
```

Answer (score 0):

That XPath will only get the span, which will not be the physical button.

Works perfectly fine here:

```
//span[contains(.,'Checkout')]/button
```

or By.CssSelector:

```
button.buttonLargeAlt
```

If still not working, explain more. Is it in an iFrame? What error does Selenium give?

Comment: Or that one yes :) As you can see, lots and lots of way to find elements.

Answer (score 0):

I have Add Attachment button:

I tried by this code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"attachments\"]/div/div/img")).sendKeys("C:\\Users\\NayazPasha\\Desktop\\Ndin selenium Testing outputs\\Collab Schedule onclick.png");
```