# Unable to click on a button in updatepanel through selenium webdriver java

Tags: java, button, selenium, webdriver, updatepanel

Below mentioned is html details of Accept/Reject button.

```html
<div id="ContentPlaceHolder1_EmployeeProfile_divAction" class="btn-row btn-accept-recet" style="display:block;">
  <button onclick="__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$EmployeeProfile$btnAccept','')" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_EmployeeProfile_btnAccept" class="btn pull-left btn-primary" type="button">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Accept
  </button>
  <button onclick="__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$EmployeeProfile$btnReject','')" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_EmployeeProfile_btnReject" class="btn pull-left btn-primary" type="button">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Reject
  </button>
</div>
```

I wanted to click on accept or reject button in update-panel. I tried using actions:

```html
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("ContentPlaceHolder1_EmployeeProfile_btnAccept"));
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.moveToElement(element).click().perform();
```

Comment: Are you getting any exception?

Comment: Yes...because driver was not able to find the button.

so i made driver to scroll down the page as button was lying at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following could before clicking the required button :-

```
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
  WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("someid")));
```

Let me know if this works......Happy to help.....

Also, Try using xpath to locate the element....the xpath in your case could be something as follows :-

```
//div[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_EmployeeProfile_divAction']/button[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_EmployeeProfile_btnAccept']
```

If the above also doesn't work then try using the following code :-

```
var btnAccept = GetElementWaitVisibleThrow(By.Id("<<ELEMENT HTMLID>>"));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.MoveByOffset(btnAccept.Location.X + 5, btnAccept.Location.Y + 5).Click().Perform();
```

OR may be following code :-

```
// Find an element and define it
WebElement elementToClick = driver.findElement(By.xpath("some xpath"));
// Scroll the browser to the element's Y position
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,"+elementToClick.getLocation().y+")");
// Click the element
elementToClick.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at related problems like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176170/how-can-i-click-on-a-button-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java)?

That suggests using something like:
`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/button[text()='Accept' and @class='btn-primary']")).click();`

Comment: Driver is unable to find the element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **either of the below codes to click on 'Accept' button:**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_EmployeeProfile_divAction']/button[1]")).click();
```

**OR**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_EmployeeProfile_divAction']/button[.='Accept']")).click();
```

---

And, You can use **either of the below codes to click on 'Reject' button:**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_EmployeeProfile_divAction']/button[2]")).click();
```

**OR**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_EmployeeProfile_divAction']/button[.='Reject']")).click();
```

Comment: Getting this error: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (82, 857). Other element would receive the click

Comment: Which option did you try ?

Comment: Both options of accept. Though my test case executed successfully, but the "Accept" button was not clicked by the selenium driver.

Comment: Are the button(s) visible on the webpage or does it appear sometime after the page load?

Comment: Got through this issue, I made driver to scroll down to the bottom of the page(as button was at the bottom of the form) and driver clicks the button..!! 

driver.manage().window().maximize();
WebElement scroll = driver.findElement(By.id("ContentPlaceHolder1_EmployeeProfile_btnAccept"));
scroll.sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN);
driver.findElement(By.id("ContentPlaceHolder1_EmployeeProfile_btnAccept"));
driver.findElement(By.id("ContentPlaceHolder1_EmployeeProfile_btnAccept")).click();

Anyway Thanks guyss..for sharing your views..!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below approach

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(.,'Accept')]".submit();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(.,'Reject')]".submit();
```

Comment: Driver doesn't clicked on the button. Just passed the line and executed the test case.

Comment: pls post your complete code so that we know where issue arises

Answer (score -1):

```
driver.manage().window().maximize(); 
WebElement scroll = driver.findElement(By.id("ContentPlaceHolder1_EmployeeProfile_btnAccept"));   
scroll.sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN);   
driver.findElement(By.id("ContentPlaceHolder1_EmployeeProfile_btnAccept")).click‌​();
```